# positioning layout in android

Tags: android, layout, android-relativelayout, stretch

I have something like to this:

[image]

I want that when the relative_layout stretch to fill the screen, stretch layout_content (layout_header and layout_footer not resize). 
And when the screen size is smaller than layouts then scrool

My code currently looks like this:

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:gravity="center">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_header">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_below="@+id/layout_center">
            ...
        </LinearLayout>


    </RelativeLayout >
</ScrollView>
```

Excuse my english, thank you very much. I Wear long time without this fix and have tried with different layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this..

```
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="top"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_center"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="center"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout_footer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="bottom"
                android:textSize="20dp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place the `ScrollView` only for `LinearLayout`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_header"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
     android:fillViewport="true">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_center"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_header">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>
       </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout_footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_below="@+id/layout_center">
        ...
    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout >
```

Comment: Thank you. But I want to scroll the entire page not only the center.